# How do I find the decimal part of the answer of a logarithm problem

Tags: logarithms

This isn't a homework question, just something I'm curious about, but you can treat it that way if you like. I have been trying to solve logarithm problems with decimal answer.

For example `log base 2 of 6` :

$$ \log_2 6 = 2.584962500721156 $$

Another example `log base 3 of 8` :

$$ \log_3 8 =  1.8927892607 $$

Overall :

$$ \log_X Y =  0.000000000 $$

It's not about a particular **base**.

Please tell me how do I find the decimal part of the answers ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Newton's method?

Comment: I just want to find the decimal part. I don't care with what method :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm , http://courses.ischool.berkeley.edu/i255/f01/resources/Base2Logs.html

Comment: Since this is a nonlinear equation, and you really want to do it by hand, I would suggest Newton's method on the equation $2^z-6=0$.

Comment: @HamedKamrava Nice Question for me too.

Comment: Your answer depends on how many digits you want in your answer.  If you only want 4 or 5, then you want to learn to use logarithm tables.  If you need more, then you want to use one of the techniques suggested above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow yourself a calculator but not [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%282,6%29), you can use the laws of logarithms: $\log_a(b)=\frac {\log_e(b)}{\log_e(a)}$.  Scientific calculators will have a button for $\ln x$

If you are doing it with just pencil and paper, you are in for a lot of work to get many decimals.  The best approach I can imagine is successive approximation using square roots and conversion to natural logs.  If you know the old pencil and paper approach to [calculating square roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots) you can get within any dyadic fraction you want.  So $\log_2 6=2+\log_2 1.5=2.5+\log_2 \frac {1.5}{\sqrt 2}\approx 2.5+\log_2 1.06066$  Now if you know $\ln 2 \approx 0.693147$, this becomes $\log_2 6\approx 2.5+\frac {\ln 1.06066}{0.693147}$ and you can evaluate the numerator using a Taylor's series rather quickly.  If you don't know that $\ln 3 \approx 1.0986$ you can use $\ln 3 = 1+ \ln \frac 3e$ and again use the Taylor series for the last.